# SUM with distinct multiple lines

Tags: oracle, sum

DB: ORACLE

Hi guys. I am constructing a query and I have the follow situation:

My table

```
---------------------------------------
Risk         Risk Factor     Control
---------------------------------------
RK 1            RF 1         Control 1
RK 1            RF 1         Control 2
RK 2            RF 3         Control 1
---------------------------------------
```

So I'd like to sum how much Risks Factors I have per risks e how much controls I have per Risk too.

Result

```
--------------------------------------
Risk         SUM RF     SUM Control
--------------------------------------
RK 1            1            2
RK 2            1            1
--------------------------------------
```

Does anyone knows how to fix this problem?

Kind Regards

---

I tried a simple sum. I created a view when a have the relation between Risk Factor and Control so I made a join with risk table, example:

```
SELECT RK.NAME, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN RFC.RISKFACTOR IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0) SUM_RK, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN RFC.CONTROL IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0) SUM_CONTROL 
FROM T_RISK RK 
JOIN V_RF_CONTROL RFC 
ON RFC.RELATIONID = RK.RISKID
```

Comment: Group by first two fields and count() the third ?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yeah I tried a simple sum. I created a view when a have the relation between Risk Factor and Control so I made a join with risk table, example: 

SELECT 
RK.NAME,
SUM(CASE WHEN RFC.RISKFACTOR IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0) SUM_RK,
SUM(CASE WHEN RFC.CONTROL IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0) SUM_CONTROL
FROM T_RISK RK
JOIN V_RF_CONTROL RFC
ON RFC.RELATIONID = RK.RISKID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to sum here - you just need to count the distinct values:

```
SELECT RK.NAME, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT RFC.RISKFACTOR) SUM_RK, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT RFC.CONTROL) SUM_CONTROL 
FROM   T_RISK RK 
JOIN   V_RF_CONTROL RFC ON RFC.RELATIONID = RK.RISKID
```